# Assessing students in exams with negative points?

Tags: teaching, grading

I've seen that some math teachers design tests which punish errors with negative points.

Why do they assign negative points?  What are some pedagogical reasons why teachers might do this?

Comment: Some standardized tests use negative points to prevent guessing on multiple choice problems. Other times stuff it "required" but not given any points (pre-lab work for example). Ultimately it's up to the teacher, and they can assign any grade they want - but it's generally better to be consistent (i.e. a wrong negative sign is always -.5 pts, etc.), as that makes it easier for students to understand and creates less back and forth discussions over the grades.

Comment: Related: [Is it dishonest to guess on multiple choice exams?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/21122/is-it-dishonest-to-guess-on-multiple-choice-exams)

Comment: I'm afraid I have to give +1 for the user name in confluence with the question.

Comment: In Germany, this is illegal. (iirc) Note also that you only have this problem (caused by guessing being a valid strategy for exams) if you pose uninspired MC exams. Better exams don't have this issue.

Comment: @Raphael Really? Doesn't the government have better things to do with its time than making laws about how people mark multiple-choice exams?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't know if there's actual law/regulation, but there are court rulings to that effect (prompted by students suing after failing an exam). Basically, it was ruled that you may not "take away" points earned on one problem by assigning negative points to another. Hence, points on problems/questions have to be non-negative.

Comment: @Raphael Ah, I'd forgotten case-law.

Comment: @Raphael: but it is perfectly OK (and frequently done) in Germany to subtract points for certain types of error within a question (wrong sign, parenthesis error, missing axis units, wrong/missing unit, etc).

Comment: @cbeleites Yes, certainly. Many such grading schemes can be transformed into their positive dual, though: award points for correct/present things and sum up (as opposed to penalising for wrong/missing things).

Comment: At my university a student got a negative grade due to wrongly answering too many multiple-choice questions. Then a "root factor" was applied to everybody's grade, i.e. `newGrade = sqrt(grade) + grade`. **This student therefore had the dubious honour of being the first student in university history to receive a complex number as his final grade.**

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Germany doesn't have case law - I forgot what its type of law is called: one ruling doesn't set necessarily enforceable law for other cases. Also, being German, as a kid I remember our biology high school teacher (also a monk) once giving an F+F for an exam where "one fail wouldn't have done justice to this level of incompetence" (which I'd call the extreme level of negative points; albeit at high school level). And he was everyone's favorite teacher.

Comment: My aunt once scored -7 on a scale from 1 to 10.  It was a secondary school vocabulary test and the teacher simply subtracted one point for each wrong answer.  This was in the 1960s; I think it is now illegal.

Comment: Note that you could avoid negative grading on multiple choice by awarding for example 2 points for a correct answer, 1 for no answer, and 0 for an incorrect answer. Not sure whether or not this would outwit those German judges, though ;-) Their objection to "taking away points" may or may not also cause them to object to "awarding points for doing nothing".

Comment: @SteveJessop IIRC, that exact approach is used for some American high school math contests.

Comment: and who's to say the negative points eventually lead to a negative grade? I've had teachers do that, they just stopped correcting on reaching the number of negative points needed to reach a 0 (or 1, school I went to never graded below 1-, different scale, same principle).

Comment: @gnometorule What you say about case law is correct (afaik) but strong precedence (meaning you are *likely* to lose in court) is equivalent to something being illegal in practice, unless you are prepared to fight. (Which universities usually don't seem to be, both regarding willingness and competence.)

Comment: @cpast Definitely regional/per-competition, if it is done; [WYSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldwide_Youth_in_Science_and_Engineering) had no penalty for incorrect guesses when I was in it

Comment: @Izkata It is done. I remember it in the math competitions I competed in when I was in high school. One of them, for instance, was graded out of 200 possible points. There were 40 multiple-choice questions with 5 options each. You started out with 40 points and got +4 for a correct answer and -1 for an incorrect answer. This meant that blind guessing would average out to no effect while educated guessing was still more likely to be in your favor. The American Mathematic Competition follows a similar scheme with +6 for correct, +1.5 for no answer and 0 for incorrect.

Comment: Concerning Germany, specifically, it is forbidden in North Rhine-Westphalia: http://www.pflichtlektuere.com/16/05/2012/multiple-choice-verwirrung-um-minuspunkte/

Answer (score 60):

> Grade that goes below zero doesn't make sense.

What makes you say that?  In some real-world scenarios, thinking you know the answer and being wrong is worse than realizing you don't know.  For example, I'd rather have my doctor or lawyer recognize when something goes beyond their expertise, so I can consult a specialist rather than following mistaken advice.  I imagine the same is true for most professionals, such as engineers.

If not answering at all yields a grade of zero, then it's reasonable to award negative points for a truly bad answer.  (Of course an insightful but flawed answer may still deserve a positive score, just not as high as the correct answer.)

In practice the most common case I've seen negative scores used is multiple choice exams, for the [reason given by GeneMachine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/31230/), but one can make a philosophical case for applying them much more broadly.

Comment: +1 The answer makes a lot of sense, but a sidetrack question is - how many docs would admit before their patients that they have no clue what ailment they are suffering from? They'll diagnose something and recommend pills even if they are not too sure!

Comment: This is an opinion-based generalisation, and is inappropriate for this forum.

Comment: @New_new_newbie It's not a doctor admitting they have no clue. It's a doctor saying, "My training and expertise leads me to believe that you have a problem with your [insert body part here], so I'm booking you an appointment with a bodypartologist." That happens *all the time*. Likewise, any time you meet a lawyer socially and ask them a question about the law, the first thing they'll say is, "I don't do that part of law. You'd need to speak to an expert on that to find the real answer."

Comment: I remember as a student seeing hard questions posed as "Can you {do something difficult}?"  As students we knew this was just the professor's polite way of saying "{do something difficult}", but I was always tempted to simply answer "Yes" or "No" and move on to the next question.  Perhaps the question should have been broken up into "Can you {do something difficult}." and "{do something difficult}" and students could get points for an honest "No".

Comment: @New_new_newbie any decent doctor knows and admits when he's not the one to help the patient, and will send you to a colleague who can help. Only a quack will kill a patient in order to sell more pills and consults.

Comment: This is exactly why in my medical genetics class there was negative points for the multi-choice exam (which were freaking hard), you really had to think and know, do not guess.  It will make it worse.  If you dont know, leave it blank.  That's what he was going for, as he primarily taught med students.

Comment: I actually did an exam once were we were made to state how certain we were of our answers on an 1-5 scale. With 1 meaning that we would probably google it with these key words and thus lose no points if we were incorrect but only earning half points and 5 meaning that we were dead certain thus earning us full points but costing twice the points if we were wrong, makes you think about what you know for certain.

Answer (score 19):

It's to discourage guessing, and to avoid mark inflation.

There are many discussions of negative marking available; here is one:

http://teach.southwales.ac.uk/assessment/negativemarking/

Answer (score 19):

To give an (imperfect) analogy, on Stack Exchange posts can get negative points, thus making the poster  *lose* reputation. The reason is to prevent users from posting low-quality posts in the hopes of getting a few upvotes. Downvotes force the user to only post if he's confident it's a good idea.

Similarly, giving points for correct answers on a test, while ignoring incorrect answers, encourages random guessing. Taking away points for wrong answers forces the students to be sure they really know the answer.

Comment: +1, though I was tempted to give -1 just for the irony.

Answer (score 8):

There are many positives and drawbacks to negative grading, even for free response tests. It encourages academic honesty and self assessment which are important for learning and discourages "BS" answers where the student knows the answer is wrong but is trying to confuse the grader into awarding some points. Some view "BS" answers as cheating. Unfortunately, negative points for wrong answers can punish students who are under-confident, and choose not to write an answer when they actually can demonstrate some understanding. It can also reward students for not even showing up to the exam if the test is hard enough.

Answer (score 6):

I see two parts in this question,

> Why negative points? Grade that goes below zero doesn't make sense.

Negative Points can make sense, as a punishment. Grades below zero not so much IMO.

I have a lecturer, who gives us assignments before the exam, we hand them in and get some points for it. 
You then start your exam with that score, but if you fail a question you get negative points. This is for the reason that the exam only tests for topics we dealt with in the assignments. 
But you don't drop below zero.

This method prevents people from coping assignments from other students beforehand.